# Storing a list of different generic types

Tags: c#, generics, tpl-dataflow

I know this is a frequently discussed topic, since I found a lot of posts talking about it. Unfornately, none of them seems to solve my problem, either because I am not understanding the solution, or I am complicating my problem.

I implemented a simple dataflow, on top of the existent TPL Dataflow library. To make it easier to test, I would like to supply a list of block connections to its constructor, for it to automatically create all blocks and their connections. For that, I created the following class:

```
internal class DataflowBlockConnection<TInput, TOutput> : IDataflowBlockConnection
{
    public ISourceBlock<TOutput> Source { get; set; }
    public ITargetBlock<TInput> Target { get; set; }
}
```

Based on this class, I created an empty interface (IDataflowBlockConnection), so that I can have a list of objects that implement it.

```
public override void CreateStructure()
{
    foreach (IDataflowBlockConnection connection in BlockConnections)
    {
        ConnectBlocks(connection.Source, connection.Target);
    }
}
```

Unfortanetly, this does not compile, since I don't have information about the Source and Target in the interface, which would allow me to connect the source to the target. That's where other threads diverge from this. With this design I can have a list of different connections with their own input and output types, but I cannot access each block, since I would need information about TInput and TOutput. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

Following @Enigmativity's comment, I have reduced my problem so that it is easier understood.

I have two types of classes, Source Blocks and Target Blocks. They both implement IDataflowBlock interface, since they are both different types of blocks. They both receive a generic type (TInput or TOutput), that can be any type.

Source Blocks can be linked to Target Blocks, but that method is only available for Source Blocks.

Following are the simplified classes (this is a short transcription of TPL Dataflow, just based on my problem):

```
internal interface IDataflowBlock
{

}

internal interface ISourceBlock<out TOutput> : IDataflowBlock
{
    void LinkTo(ITargetBlock<TOutput> target);
}

internal interface ITargetBlock<in TInput> : IDataflowBlock
{

}
```

Based on this structure, pipelines can be created, by linking different source blocks to target blocks. My idea, so that I can easily test different pipeline structures, was to create a class that would represent the connection between two blocks, so that I would only need to supply a list of connections, and the blocks would be linked based on the list.

```
internal interface IDataflowBlockConnection
{

}

internal class DataflowBlockConnection<TInput, TOutput> : IDataflowBlockConnection
{
    public ISourceBlock<TOutput> Source { get; set; }
    public ITargetBlock<TInput> Target { get; set; }
}
```

Now imagine I wanted to create a list of connections, that have different input and output types. Since the connection class implements an interface, I can do the following:

```
// Two blocks that act as source, consuming types int and char
        ISourceBlock<int> sourceInt = new SourceBlock<int>();
        ISourceBlock<char> sourceChar = new SourceBlock<char>();

        // One block that acts as target, receiving type string
        ITargetBlock<string> targetString = new TargetBlock<string>();

        // Pipeline structure:
        // sourceInt -> targetString
        // sourceChar -> targetString

        DataflowBlockConnection<string, int> connection1 = new DataflowBlockConnection<string, int>
        {
            Source = sourceInt,
            Target = targetString
        };

        DataflowBlockConnection<string, char> connection2 = new DataflowBlockConnection<string, char>
        {
            Source = sourceChar,
            Target = targetString
        };

        List<IDataflowBlockConnection> blockConnections = new List<IDataflowBlockConnection>
        {
            connection1, connection2
        };
```

This compiles, and I now have a list of the desired connections to form the pipeline. But I have no way of connecting them, since the LinkTo method belongs to Source Block.

```
foreach (IDataflowBlockConnection connection in blockConnections)
        {
            // Does not compile, since IDataflowBlockConnection has no information about Source and Target.
            connection.Source.LinkTo(Target);
        }
```

To be able to access Source and Target from IDataflowBlockConnection, without associating TInput and TOutput to it (which would ruin the possibility of having a list with different TInput and TOutput types), I changed it to this:

```
internal interface IDataflowBlockConnection
{
    ISourceBlock<TOutput> GetSource<TOutput>();
    ITargetBlock<TInput> GetTarget<TInput>();
}
```

Now I was thinking about calling these methods with reflection, which (I think, because haven't implemented) would solve my problem. My question is: am I complicating the solution? Is there an elegant solution that I am not seeing?

Comment: I'll admit that it's been a while since I looked at this stuff, so I might be missing something. Can your interface be generic? `IDataflowBlockConnection<TInput, TOutput>`?

Comment: If my interface is generic, that will enforce the value of TInput or TOutput to be the same through its lifetime, which means I lose the ability to have multi type list :/

Comment: Is it an option to use reflection?

Comment: It would be an option to use reflection, sure. I wanted to avoid it , but if it is the best option considering the circumstances, its fine

Comment: I don't think that it's possible without reflection, because the only non-generic interface implemented by the blocks is the [`IDataflowBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock), which doesn't support linking them to other blocks.

Comment: I guess I'll have to crente two methods in the interface to get each block, and use reflection to inject their types at runtime

Comment: Regarding the pipeline structure you gave as example, the `ISourceBlock<int>` -> `TargetBlock<string>`, how is this supposed to work? The source block produces integers, and the target block consumes strings. I can't see how these blocks could be linked together!

Comment: That's where TransformBlocks come in. You can have  Source block that is a TransformBlock and a target block that is another TransformBlock. The problem is the same

Comment: You can't link a `TransformBlock<Something, int>` to a `TransformBlock<string, SomethingElse>`. The output type of the producer block must match the input type of the consumer block.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled uppon dynamic, searching for solutions to my problem. One solution is to use reflection to inject the types to the method at runtime, as suggest by @Theodor Zoulias. Another solution would be to use dynamic, although it is still a controversial topic, as it depends on the situations. Is this a good one to use?

Comment: `dynamic` is good in circumstances where you are dealing with external objects like XML or JSON or DBs that have changing names for things. You're dealing with C#. There's almost always a better way to deal with C# than dynamic.

Comment: What would your suggestion be to my problem then, with that being said?

Comment: I'd love to give you an answer but the question is incomplete. I don't see the definition of you list of block connections. I don't see any constructors. I don't know what `CreateStructure` is overriding and from where. I don't see `ConnectBlocks`. Can you please provide a full [mcve] that I can copy, paste, and see the code not compile in my environment. Then I can refactor and make it work. Then I can give you an answer. The reason you don't have other answers already is because the question is incomplete. Can you please do that for me?

Comment: I updated my question so it provides more detail. I hope it is helpfull :)